# Is there a performance penalty to using a pipeline operator ponyfill instead of .pipe in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I use a pipeline operator ponyfill, which is just a utility function `applyPipe` such that `applyPipe(x, a, b)` is equivalent to `b(a(x))` or `x |> a |> b` (in this example there are 2 functions, but actually it can be any number of functions). In `fp-ts` this function is called `pipe`.

In my case the function is implemented as

```js
export const applyPipe = (
  source,
  ...project
) => {
  for (const el of project) {
    source = el(source);
  }
  return source;
};
```

(you could also implement it with `.reduce`).

This function can be used to compose observable operators, so `applyPipe(timer(500), delay(500))` is equivalent to `timer(500).pipe(delay(500))`. The question is, is there a performance penalty to using such function in place of the `.pipe` method?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, I see no major issue or performance downgrade by doing so (other than adding an extra step by using your function and copying the observable/object reference to process it in the function). You will just copy the observable reference (not the emissions of the observable) hence it's shouldn't be a big deal for performance reasons.
Also, ponyfill/polyfills are generally expected to be either equal to or worst than the actual implementation in terms of performance.  Just keep in mind that the spreading operator will copy only the properties of the object (not any nested property).

I would leave some comment in that ponyfill function to make it easier to understand for every other developer that works with your codebase.